# Upload large file .net core 3.1 api using iis without changing web.config

Tags: api, asp.net-core, file-upload, web-config

Is there any solution to uploading files larger than the default without changing the web.config?

On the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1, it says to change the web.config and to setup IISServerOptions.MaxRequestBodySize to our value, but in my current project i can't change the web.config. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Architecturally, this can be solved by having clients upload directly to cloud storage, which can handle any size and use chunked uploading. For example, in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser

Comment: But I have to create this endpoint to work as a proxy to send the file to another client, plus saving the file in a NAS.

Comment: To handle directly, I think you'd need to implement some method for chunked uploads, e.g. https://github.com/edsoncunha/chunked-file-upload-csharp

Comment: I want to accept the file as one, but iis by default only accepts 30MB, my issue is trying to change this, maybe in StartUp file but not on web.config

Comment: To increase the IIS File Upload Size Limit, there have three options:
1. Modify the web.config file. 2. [edit the ApplicationHost.config file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/http-404-13-website) 3. Edit the request filtering settings in IIS: Open the IIS Manager => select the website => double click the Request Filtering, choose the "Edit Feature Settings..." action, then in the popup model change the appropriate Maximum allowed content length (Bytes Specifying zero for this value means that the length is unlimited.) and then click the OK button. Finally restart the IIS.